# if not rest style, should I use ModelSerializer check user input?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Some situation, we just need to use normal APIView write normal view, and Serializer just check user input, it won't be save as database object.
But sometimes, I want to use the convenient of ModelSerializer, for example:

```
class User(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(_("phone number"), max_length=11, unique=True,
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(r'^1[34578]\d{9}$', _("phone format error"))
        ])

class PhoneCodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('phone',)
```

But you know, modelSerializer not only check the phone format, and check unique. But here I just want to use the format validator of phone field, otherwise I have to copy the validator to serializer, I dislike it. Is there any more better way.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that you are successful in implementing what you are asking, even though you will have the unique check applied, through the Model. So why not use it at Serializer level or am I missing something ?

Comment: i am wtring one api that you post one phone number, i response phone code. so i need to check your phone number format is right

Comment: Then you would have to write a separate validator (i.e copy the existing one). You cannot use the ModelSerializer in this case.